# Collapse rows based on another column duplicate value in R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
A <- c("A", "A123", "A123", "B123", "B123", "B")
B <- c("NA", "as", "bp", "df", "kl", "c")

df <- data.frame(A, B)
```

and I would like to create a df in which the output would be

```
A <- c("A", "A123", "B123", "B")
C <- c("NA", "as;bp", "df;kl", "c")
df2 <- data.frame(A,C)
```

This new column is based on if there is a duplicate in column A, then combine the values in column B to make a new column, all other unique values in column B that correspond single/unique values in A would be carried over to column C.

Any help in generating a code where you get column C would be appreciated as I don't even know where to begin in coding for this.
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tidyverse with `reframe` to `paste` the non-missing 'B' values for each 'A' group - `if` `all` values are missing, return the `B` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   reframe(C = if(all(is.na(B))) B else 
     str_c(B[complete.cases(B)], collapse = ";"), .by = "A")
```

-output

```
     A     C
1    A    NA
2 A123 as;bp
3 B123 df;kl
4    B     c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` and `paste`

```
setNames(aggregate(. ~ A, df, paste0, collapse=";"), c("A", "C"))
     A     C
1    A    NA
2 A123 as;bp
3    B     c
4 B123 df;kl
```